# ERROR: 2018/08/26 14:03:30 template.go:350: template: theme/_default/baseof.html:23: function "resources" not defined

Tags: hugo

I've installed hugo, created a directory and used this command : `hugo new site .`

Then I cloned the folder(`hugo-coder`) into `themes` and added the line `theme = "hugo-coder"`.

But after `hugo server -w` it's giving this error :

> ERROR: 2018/08/26 14:03:30 template.go:350: template: theme/_default/baseof.html:23: function "resources" not defined
>
> ERROR: 2018/08/26 14:03:30 template.go:350: template: theme/partials/header.html:3: function "absLangURL" not defined
>
> ERROR: 2018/08/26 14:03:30 template.go:350: template: theme/partials/post.html:38: function "default" not defined

```
0 draft content
0 future content
0 pages created
0 non-page files copied
0 paginator pages created
0 tags created
0 categories created
in 13 ms
Watching for changes in /home/insol/balkrishnajha.github.io/{data,content,layouts,static,themes}
Serving pages from memory
Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 127.0.0.1)
```

I'm using this hugo [theme](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder/).

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem resolved by updating Hugo version.

I'd installed Hugo using `sudo apt-get install Hugo` which installed 0.16 version.

Comment: Same thing ("resources") happened with v0.40.1 installed with apt in combination with the theme "spectrum". Using the deb from github (0.55.6-A5D4C82D) solved it.